# there's no way to comment inside an xml node, right?

Tags: android, xml

I'm almost positive the answer is "no" but just to be sure... there's no syntactical mechanism for commenting out portions of stuff inside an XML node, right?

In other words something like

```
<myNode
//this is not being looked at
attributeFoo = "bar"
//this is also being ignored
/>
```

I'm only asking because there is now SO much stuff that goes into Android's xml nodes that it would be nice to be able to comment stuff out, and/or label things... but I suspect I'm out of luck here...

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

There isn't. You can only put comments outside of tags. The closest thing to it is probably:

```
<myNode
 throwAway1="This is not being looked at"
 attributeFoo="bar"
 throwAway2="This is also being ignored"
/>
```

Or just use normal comments.

Comment: Ah! that's a great point, I can just alter the android param to be something like _android:... and then the Android compiler will just ignore it, right?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: I don't know, I'm not an Android person. Try it, maybe it will.

Comment: For commenting out an attr on android, it seems no variants retaining the ':' work:  (1) fudging prefix to `_android` gives "error: unbound prefix"; (2) fudging the main part of the attr name gives "error: attribute 'android:layout_widthNOT' not found; (3) putting two different values of the attr (one you want, the other you don't want, hoping one will win) gives "error: duplicate attribute.".  So it seems you have to get rid of the ':'.  I suggest changing the ':' to `NOT` or `X`; e.g. `androidNOTlayout_width="300dp"` or `androidXlayout_width="300dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. You can have a comment node... but that is as close as you can get

```
<!-- Comment! -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot comment inside a tag, but you can wrap a tag as a comment, I have found it helpful many times:

```
<!-- <Activity></Activity> -->
```

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments

Answer (score 1):

No, XML [does not allow comments inside markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-comments).